# Preferred Installation Location Setting Option Missing

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My friend has a phone with Android 4.2.1 and it has "Preferred Installation Location" option under Settings->Storage which allows to set default installation location for applications as SD Card and in another friends phone with Android 4.2.2 is missing that!! What is the scene there?? has any body come across this?

Comment: Does not seem to be a programming question. Try android.stackexchange.com for device usage questions.

Comment: next time onwards :)..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internal and external storage share a partition on many Android 3.0+ devices, meaning that installing the app to external storage is no longer necessary.

Moreover, I do not recall a global "Preferred Installation Location" option being available in any version of stock Android. My guess is that this option is unique to certain devices, or perhaps certain ROM mods.

Comment: The phone which has a global "Preferred Installation Location" option is of Brand LAVA.. an Indian brand..and one where its missing is Samsung Grand

Comment: thanks for your answer..it will be great if I get know what "certain ROM mods" means? and how sharing a partition eliminates need of installing the app to external storage?

Comment: @Rauf: "what "certain ROM mods" means?" -- http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-57578709-251/hack-your-android-like-a-pro-rooting-and-roms-explained/ "how sharing a partition eliminates need of installing the app to external storage?" -- the point of install-to-external-storage was because on Android 1.x/2.x devices internal and external storage were separate partitions, and external storage tended to be larger. Now, internal and external storage share the same space (same partition). If anything, installing to external storage would take up more of that space.

Comment: thank you so much..it did answer many more questions :)